# inherit gtkmm window class

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

How can i inherit gtk window class. what header file should be included todo so.

Thanks in advance,
iSight

Comment: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/chapter-customwidgets.html.en

Comment: @pTomato: This means i cannot customize widgets with gtkmm 2.4

Comment: @pTomato: When i go through the examples from the link you provide, it is specifically mentioned on gtkmm3 and not gtkmm2

Comment: @iSight: Sorry, I was looking at the "unstable" documentation instead of the "stable". Here is the link: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-custom-containers.html.en

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
```

The Hello World example does it:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-helloworld.html.en